# @Configuration not working for Bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following code, where in i am trying to create a bean out of the return type of the method.

It give error while starting the application as below:

> Error creating bean with name 'myMap' defined in class path resource
>   [com/test/MyServiceImpl.class]: No matching factory method found:
>   factory bean 'MyServiceImpl'; factory method 'myMap()'. Check that a
>   method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
{

  @Autowired
  private MyDao myDao;

  @Override
  @Bean
  @Scope("singleton")
  @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
  public Map<String, String> myMap() 
  {
    return myDao.getMapFromDB();
  }

}


public interface MyService
{

  Map<String, String> myMap() 
}
```

My application is based spring mvc and I have added the relevant configuration in the xml.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan>
```

Comment: @Configuration is used for configuring the spring applciation the "Java Way" rather than using xml configuration. It should not implement any interface. remove the implements MyService. Is there any concrete implementation of MyService exists ? Is it marked with @Component/@Service ??

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm example for this

Comment: Ok then how should I go about in creating a bean out of the methods return value.

Comment: Did you comply with all of these?
Configuration classes must be non-final
Configuration classes must be non-local (may not be declared within a method)
Configuration classes must have a default/no-arg constructor and may not use @Autowired constructor parameters. Any nested configuration classes must be static

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you try to do, but here's an approach which would work:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  @Autowired
  private MyDao myDao;

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
  public Map<String, String> myMap() {
    return myDao.getMapFromDB();
  }
}

interface MyService {
  Map<String, String> myMap() 
}
```

This would define your service implementation as a Spring-managed `@Service`. Your `MyDao` would automatically be injected and you can use it in your method.

If you want that your `MyDao` has a certain scope (singleton is already the default), than you would annotate the `MyDao` class.

If you want to write a configuration, you would need to do it like this:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig { 
    public MyService myService() {
          return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}
```